# How do you pass a variable in a function when adding an action to wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that needs the wordpress global $post. So i have written it like so:

```
function custom_function($post){//stuff}
```

I have added the function to the wp_head:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_function');
```

Is there a way to pass the function the variable through the action? the only solution I can come up with is setting global $post inside the function, but that's not good practice.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments parameter in `do_action` function like below.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_function','10',1);
do_action( 'wp_head', $post);
```

Read [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) for more.

**Note:** To use like `global $post;` is totally fine. It dosen't consider as bad practice specifically for wp.

Comment: The 4th parameter is the accepted arguments, for what he wants do he needs do_action() after add_action()

Comment: @Rikesh the first param of do_action is the hook name not the function :P

Comment: :p hope everything is fine now :)